# Comparing a string created from a char[]

Tags: java, string, compare

My code compares the equality between two words. It prints a value "TRUE" if the strings are equal. Else it returns false. Java "equals" function is being used

```
class k{  

    public static void main(String args[]){  
        String s1="Sach";  
        String s2=word();  
        String s3=new String("Sach");   
        System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));  
        System.out.println(s1.equals(s3));      
    } 

    public static String word() {
        char[] str=new char[100];
        str[0]='S';
        str[1]='a';
        str[2]='c';
        str[3]='h';
        String ss=new String(str);
        System.out.println(ss);
        return ss;
    }
}
```

I need to fetch some selected alphabets into an array and convert it to string. After this conversion, the function returns the string. But comparison results in an incorrect value. Is there some other method to convert the array to string so that this program gives a correct result.

Comment: They're not the same though - `s2` has 96 trailing `'\0'` characters. Change `char[] str = new char[100]` to `char[] str = new char[4]`.

Comment: try to print the length of s2. You will understand

Comment: *"fetch some selected [**alphabets**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabet)"* Why would you want to fetch the letters from A to Z, or whichever is appropriate for language of choice, and then show an example returning `Sach`? Those 4 letters do not constitute an *alphabet*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The character array you are creating the new `String` from in your method has more then 4 characters so of course it will not equal the other `String`.

To be precise your array is holding the 4 characters you specified and another 96 null characters ('\u0000') since you didn't specify a value and the default is used.

Update the method to only specify an array of 4 characters like below and you will get the expected results.:

```
public static String word() {
    char[] str = new char[4];
    str[0] = 'S';
    str[1] = 'a';
    str[2] = 'c';
    str[3] = 'h';
    String ss = new String(str);
    System.out.println(ss);
    return ss;
}
```

Also as mentioned in comments you can clean up the method to not have to specify the array length as follows:

```
public static String word() {
    char[] str = new char[] {'S', 'a', 'c', 'h'};
    return new String(str);
}
```

Comment: Or `char[] str = {'S', 'a', 'c', 'h'};`

Comment: Or `String ss= new String(str,0,4);`

Comment: @AndyTurner Well of course. I only fixed what was directly related to the question. Is it best to also clean up code when answering?

Comment: Why not - if you are going to change the length of the array to give the desired behaviour, it is worth pointing out that you don't need to be explicit about the array length in the first place.

Comment: @AndyTurner Ok I made an update. Thanks.